# Using VARCHAR keys or INT

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, primary-key, datatypes, data-warehouse

I'm building a Data Warehouse in MySQL based on [yelp dataset](https://www.yelp.com/dataset_challenge).

Most of the keys in the dataset are given as strings:

```
user_id                 review_id               business_id
hzw-qTUVpmLAKjdkoUNh8A  Awq_6cyNjK1-qPZAwnXjjQ  7p6tHUA1Pknh0DVWqz86lA
mldKxVI59o3LhK3ITG6mnA  96YkAuJzlT54qZZWNebFUg  7p6tHUA1Pknh0DVWqz86lA
SaedHW9i7k4lHR8tgwtMgQ  OfZRG7RgKA118zDtj6yo-g  7p6tHUA1Pknh0DVWqz86lA
```

Should I transfer them to self-generated keys (Auto-increment Integers) or leave them as is (`VARCHAR(22)`).

What are the considerations in Primary/Foreign Keys data type selection?

Thanks

Comment: Smells like `BASE64(UNHEX(MD5(something)))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a clear-cut answer to your question without more information. However, your choice should be basically based on:

1. **Ease of data loading**: if you leave the keys as they are, you'll save a lot of trouble creating the equivalent `INTEGER` ids (you would need an equivalence table between every pair; and use this translation table when you import the data using an [ETL process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load)). If all keys are 22 chars in length, you're probably better of using `char(22)` instead of `varchar(22)` <sup>1</sup>. (Against AUTO_INCREMENT)
2. **Size**: if the size of your dataset is very large, making the translation will save you a significant amount of space in both table rows and indexes. If there are lots of indexes with several `varchar(22)` and extra columns, you can hit the limit on index size <sup>2</sup>. The smaller the indexes (and tables) the more performant a system is to query. (Pro AUTO_INCREMENT)
3. **New keys**: if you want to add more rows to your dataset, it will be easier to have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` key than to have a mechanism to generate `varchar(22)` unique ids. (Pro AUTO_INCREMENT)

Depending on your particular needs, balance the pros and cons, and choose.

Given the nature of the [Yelp Dataset](https://www.yelp.com/dataset_challenge/dataset), I'd probably go for the `INT`, just for *size* efficiency. You'll need to translate `business_id`, `review_id`, `user_id` and `photo_id`. Provided you'll have to translate from JSON to CSV already, and convert arrays to normalized subtables, before being able to upload the different *collections*, doing one extra step shouldn't be that difficult.

---

**Notes**:

1. > If your content is a fixed size, you'll get better performance with CHAR.

   from: [What's the difference between VARCHAR and CHAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885630/whats-the-difference-between-varchar-and-char)
2. > maximum index key length is 1536 bytes when the page size is 8KB, and 768 bytes when the page size is 4KB.

   from [14.8.1.7 Limits on InnoDB Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-restrictions.html)

---

**Side note**: Consider using [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) and [MADLib](http://madlib.incubator.apache.org). I think this combination might give you some useful tools for this kind of challenge.

Comment: Further more make it `CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin` !

Answer (score 0):

For *huge* datasets, UUIDs, MD5s, or other "random" strings is terrible on performance.  Or at least when the index is too big to be cached in RAM.

This is because the 'next' key is unlikely to be the least bit related to, or near, any keys you have recently seen.  That is, "caching" becomes not useful.  If the data is 20 times as big as the cache, then 95% (1-1/20) of the time there will be a disk hit.

But, you are stuck with these ugly shrings.  You could strink them slightly without creating new ids:  `FROM_BASE64(CONCAT('7p6tHUA1Pknh0DVWqz86lA', '=='))` and put that into a `BINARY(16)` column.  Well that only shrinks 22 bytes to 16.

If you create an auto_increment from the strings, you will simply be trading a longer *random* string to a shorter one.  The cache problem still exists, but might be forestalled some.

I suggest living with

```
CHAR(22) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin
```